# Select properties from an object against a list of keys

Tags: typescript

I have an object with the following shape:

```
const belongings = {
  car: {wheels:4},
  house: {size:88},
  guitar: {brand:'gibson'}
};


type Belongings = typeof belongings
```

And I would like to create a function that does the following:

```
selectBelongings('car', 'guitar') // returns an object of type Pick<Belongings, 'car' | 'guitar'>
```

How can I accomplish this ?

I have tried to implement the function in [this snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAIwKYBtIHMCWF1TgXjgG9g44QBDAJwC5iB3ACyVShoBYBfAGlLkbABXKEjpEomAF6iAHDJ590gzDGpiEVChAAmNAORYEUSHs7BOAbmDAYATwAOSOACFUGbLgJw7jsADNENxwPKGsfJ1c0YJwAFQckPEIAayRbfxcgrBxQ63BoeBEUJBAYSPdsrwAKADpawuKYJF0MqKz0OMcoAG0AXQBKAgA%20Yj482DgqBMEUGDoABWoYTAoUAB4y6NxhwiJOMmsyPzAqOEqx%20BUkAFsOp3T6kqaBkjIySahpmC7Lm-ier2QrRC30av0cPT4ZjeSBggioEAmUxm5iAA) but obviously I'm not attacking the problem by the right angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have:

```js
const belongings = {
  car: { wheels: 4 },
  house: { size: 88 },
  guitar: { brand: 'gibson' }
};

type Belongings = typeof belongings

const selectBelongings = <T extends keyof Belongings>(...keys: readonly T[]) =>
  keys.reduce((acc, elem) => ({
    ...acc,
    [elem]: belongings[elem]
  }), {} as Pick<Belongings, T>)

const result = selectBelongings('car', 'house')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgUwDbgOYEsyojAvDAbwCgYZgBDAJwC5CYB3ACwWQloBYYBfAGhJkYgArhAS0CMCOgBeYmAA553PqVRD0UKuPiVyYACa0A5BjgRwR7kS4BuIkSgBPAA4IYAIWRpM2PDCeuIABm8F5YPhD2oJCwokgIwFCeKOFYOPgAPAAqMAgAHlAIBjgA1giOwR5hGGkAfAAUAHTNZY5sMJQI5PrgSI4wWQDaALoAlHi1-K0QjZ36QsAI9fXkwMA8ufEAtuO4tTD1xKSkzY2r6-ykg8gIW8O0iCk12Nfbw-xcoxsEXDDkOAAFdDAEoZZLeNIbLK1UZRcDQDoICBCJCwfBxBJJaoRepGCiUIwbIyCEQIIywoA)

Comment: @Lev vous êtes les bienvenus )